# How to Find Max Value in Entire 2D Array (Processing)

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array, processing

I have a 2D array that has random values assigned to it. I am looking to find the highest value in this 2D array so I can display it as text.

I was trying to use this loop to do this, however, it only gives me the last value in the array.

```
  for (iRow=0; iRow<10; iRow++)
  {
    for (iCol=0; iCol<4; iCol++)
    {
      iHighestMark=0;

      if (iArray[iRow][iCol]>iHighestMark)
      { 
        iHighestMark=iArray[iRow][iCol];

      }
    }
  }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You should assign iHighestMark to zero once, not every time on inside loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 iHighestMark=0;

 for (iRow=0; iRow<10; iRow++)
  {
    for (iCol=0; iCol<4; iCol++)
    {

      if (iArray[iRow][iCol]>iHighestMark)
      { 
        iHighestMark=iArray[iRow][iCol];

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great. I was just wondering tho, how come if I put the text inside of the loop, it displays multiple numbers. However, once i put it outside of the loop, it displays the correct number?

Comment: Assuming 2 row 3 col... In ur code : go 1st row > go 1st col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark > 2nd col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark  >  3rd col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark  > end col 1, go 2nd row > go 1st col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark > 2nd col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark  >  3rd col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark  > end row 2, go 3rd row > go 1st col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark > 2nd col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark  >  3rd col > HiMark = 0 > ChkHiMark  > end row 3, end row 2.  || So HiMark is re-set to zero @ every col iteration. , HiMark = 0 should only happen once.

Answer (score 1):

As p.*phidot* was saying, you need to initialize the variable **outside** for loop or else, the max value will reset to zero every time the program goes through the loop. The new code fixes the problem, but if all the numbers in the matrix are negative, I advise this change in the code:

```
iHighestMark = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (iRow = 0; iRow < 10; iRow++) {

   for (iCol = 0; iCol < 4; iCol++) {

      if (iArray[iRow][iCol]>iHighestMark) {

         iHighestMark=iArray[iRow][iCol];

      }
   }
}
```